# Collection Check Boxes Simple Form не записывает информацию в поле модели

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

Я использую Simple Form для записи полей БД:

```
<%= simple_form_for @eproject do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :system_type, [['Convertor1', 'Type1'] ,['Convertor2', 'Type2']], :first, :last %>
```

Где

```
create_table "eprojects", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "system_type"
...
end
```

Если заменить check_boxes на radio_buttons, в поле system_type записывается Convertor1 или Convertor2. В случае check_boxes никакой записи вобще не происходит, или поле изначально пустое или в нём остаётся предыдущая запись через radio_buttons.

HTML получается следующий:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="eproject[system_type][]" value="" /><span><label for="eproject_system_type_convertor1"><input type="checkbox" value="Convertor1" name="eproject[system_type][]" id="eproject_system_type_convertor1" /><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="eproject_system_type_convertor1">Type1</label></label></span><span><label for="eproject_system_type_convertor2"><input type="checkbox" value="Convertor2" name="eproject[system_type][]" id="eproject_system_type_convertor2" /><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="eproject_system_type_convertor2">Type2</label></label></span>
```

Параметры, передающиеся в контроллер:

```
Processing by EprojectsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {... "eproject"=>{"name"=>"Project 1", ..., "system_type"=>["", "Convertor1"]}, ...}
...
Unpermitted parameter: system_type
```

Как это победить? Спасибо

Comment: Какой html вы получаете в форме, какие параметры прилетают в контроллер, и что у вас в контроллере?

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгий ответ..

Comment: `<%= f.input :system_type, as: :check_boxes, collection: [['Convertor1', 'Type1'] ,['Convertor2', 'Type2']], label_method: :second, value_method: :first %>` даёт такой же странный результат с "" в парамсах?

Comment: Да, тот же результат..

Answer (score 0):

Видимо дело в том, что Check Boxes отправляет массив ["", "Convertor1"], а Radio Buttons строку "Convertor1". Никак не соображу как это правильно использовать в моём случае.